# Batch export to shapefile by attribute field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, attribute-table, export

I have a project in QGIS where I am creating a map of plants over a large area. I want to take the "Genus" field (of which there are 100 hundred values) and essentially create 100 shapefiles based on each individual genus name. Eventually I'll have it set up in Geoserver and set filters from a main postGIS database, but for now I'm just playing with shapefiles for concept.

Are there any efficient ways to do this through QGIS, or are there other options that will accomplish the same purpose?

Comment: If every geometry is associated with only one genus (which is possible, but I doubt it), you can use the Spit vector layer tool to make individual shapefiles. You can find it on the following path: Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Spit vector layer.

Comment: What you should consider for your final solution is perhaps to use SQLView layers in Geoserver http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html. Split vector layer feels good for creating those 100 shapefiles for testing. OpenJUMP has similar in Edit - Extract - Extract layer by attribute.

Comment: The split vector layer tool worked perfect! Thank you! also the SQLView layers is a great idea, thank you for the tip :)